# How to Use New Android Support Library(Appcompat v7) in Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I know many of you will think that the question is a duplicate or is answered already a number of times but still am having a issue in Using Android Support Library.

I use Eclipse Neon with Latest sdk version 23.

Almost Everywhere it is told that i have to import the appcompat-v7 from:
File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7)

But the problem here is there is no project exists in this directory. Instead of any project there are many sub folders in the main folder 'appcompat-v7' and an xml named as maven-metadata.xml. 
those Subfolders have some aar files in them but not any project to import.

in some solutions i saw that appcompatv7 project is automatically being created at time when you create a new project like in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CG_HxvV44zM

but also thats not true in my case. 
eclipse only creates one project with lots and lots of error in it.
I Updated ADT, SDK, Support Library(Revision 41) but that didn't helped too.

Do Help Guys, I already Referred to Dozens of Solution here in Stackoverflow and many from other sites but the issue is as it is.

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html Let's switch to Android Studio...Simple solution!

Comment: @Mohsen I tried but android studio works very slowly and sometimes even crashes due to less specification whereas Eclipse works great in Current Specification and also i am habitual of it.